# Extract a subset of XML file using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML file:

```
<Response>
    <errorCode>error Code</errorCode>
    <errorMessage>msg</errorMessage>
    <ResponseParameters>
        <className>
            <attribute1>a</attribute1>
            <attribute2>b</attribute2>
        </className>
    </ResponseParameters>
</Response>
```

And I want the output to be:

```
<className>
    <attribute1>a</attribute1>
    <attribute2>b</attribute2>
</className>
```

My current XSL file is including also "ResponseParameters" tag, which I do not want.

**EDIT: note that the node className is dynamic. I do not know what will be this name at runtime.**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:copy-of select="//ResponseParameters">
        </xsl:copy-of>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Use** :

```
<xsl:copy-of select="/Response/ResponseParameters/node()"/>
```

**The `"//"` abbreviation is very expensive** (causes the complete XML document to be scanned), **and should be avoided**.

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:copy-of select="Response/ResponseParameters//*"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to pass a parameter containing the node name into the XSLT and use the parameter passed in with the name() function to match the dynamic node.

Edit:

But in this simple case either of the other answers suggesting ResponseParameters//* or ResponseParameters/* are a far simpler solution.