# How to generate specific xml results from an xml file using xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt

Using the xml below, could you help me with the xsl transform code that would be required to complete the following:

Current XML:

```
<ROOTNODE>
  <SUBNODE1>
<DETAILS>
  <SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
  <UNIMPORTANT1>Thing</UNIMPORTANT1>
</DETAILS>
<SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>This</SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>
<ALSOUNIMPORTANT>Very</ALSOUNIMPORTANT>
  </SUBNODE1>
</ROOTNODE>
```

Output XML:

```
<DETAILS>
  <SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
</DETAILS>
<SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>This</SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Stack Overflow isn't a place to have code written for you, it's a place to get help with code you've written.

Comment: Why do you expect that anyone will try to read and compare two long  *single line* XML documents? Please, edit and format properly.

Comment: ok i'll edit and format this, i've never posted here before i didn't think that would be a concern as a developer. i've tried a few things and none of them have worked so i've tossed them out - didn't think they were worth posting, spent a day searching and trying out things - basically pulling my hair out over it now and just want to figure it out it seems like it would be simple! :/

Comment: btw one of the things i tried was your post [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/586631/extract-a-subset-of-xml-file-using-xsl?rq=1[/link] @Dimitre and it didn't quite do it - it stripped the element names out and only showed the text in the subnodes.. any ideas would be appreciated

Comment: @Peter, Why, this is quite easy, fundamental and straightforward -- see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*|/*/*"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), 'UNIMPORTANT')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<ROOTNODE>
    <SUBNODE1>
        <DETAILS>
            <SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
            <UNIMPORTANT1>Thing</UNIMPORTANT1>
        </DETAILS>
        <SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>This</SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>
        <ALSOUNIMPORTANT>Very</ALSOUNIMPORTANT>
    </SUBNODE1>
</ROOTNODE>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<DETAILS>
   <SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
</DETAILS>
<SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>This</SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>
```

Comment: that accomplished things exactly thank you very much! :)
as i move forward with xsl rules do you have any books or other online references you might recommend for me to look into? thanks again dimitre it's great to be able to move onto the next part of the project!

Comment: @Peter, You are always welcome. Here I have listed some of the most valuable XSLT/XPath resources: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339930/any-good-xslt-tutorial-book-blog-site-online/341589#341589

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <newroot>
            <DETAILS>
                <xsl:copy-of select="//DETAILS/SOMETHING"/>
            </DETAILS>
            <xsl:copy-of select="//SOMEWHATIMPORTANT"/>
        </newroot>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Update

I use the following ANT project to run this stylesheet, called **transform.xml**

```
.
├── build.xml
├── data.xml
└── transform.xsl
```

Running the project produces the following output:

```
$ ant && cat build/data.xml
Buildfile: /home/mark/tmp/build.xml

transform:
     [xslt] Processing /home/mark/tmp/data.xml to /home/mark/tmp/build/data.xml
     [xslt] Loading stylesheet /home/mark/tmp/transform.xsl

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newroot>
<DETAILS>
<SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
</DETAILS>
<SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>This</SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>
</newroot>
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="xslt-demo" default="transform">

    <target name="transform">
        <xslt style="transform.xsl" in="data.xml" out="build/data.xml"/>
    </target>

    <target name="clean">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

### data.xml

```
<ROOTNODE>
  <SUBNODE1>
<DETAILS>
  <SOMETHING>Here</SOMETHING>
  <UNIMPORTANT1>Thing</UNIMPORTANT1>
</DETAILS>
<SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>This</SOMEWHATIMPORTANT>
<ALSOUNIMPORTANT>Very</ALSOUNIMPORTANT>
  </SUBNODE1>
</ROOTNODE>
```

Comment: this one didn't work for me but thank you for trying to help!

Comment: @Peter It works (I've updated my answer with my tests). Don't worry about it, Dimitre's answer is much better than mine.