# Extract part of an XML table using XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

First off, my question is a lot like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/586631/extract-a-subset-of-xml-file-using-xsl?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), but with some variation and my current output is the opposite of what I am seeing in that linked question. Here are the details of my problem:

The objective is to remove all the `table` tags from around tables that contain images and no other content. I cannot have these images inside of a table.

Here is the input XML I am trying to transform:

```
    <table  frame="all">
        <tgroup cols="1">
            <colspec colname="col1" colwidth="480pt"/>
            <thead>
                <row>
                    <entry valign="middle">
                        <p>
                            <image href="Images/image33.png" width="770.0" height="122.0">
                                <alt>../../topics/media/image33.wmf</alt>
                            </image><i >italic image title</i>
                        </p>
                    </entry>
                </row>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <row>
                    <entry/>
                </row>
            </tbody>
        </tgroup>
    </table>
```

Here is the output I am looking for:

```
<fig>
    <title>image title</title>
    <image href="Images/image33.png" width="770.0" height="122.0"></image>
</fig>
```

I can add the `<fig>` tags by using this template:

```
<xsl:template match="table//image">
    <xsl:element name="fig">
        <xsl:element name="image">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

but when I add this template (answer from linked question above):

```
<xsl:template match="table//image">
    <xsl:copy-of select="/tgroup/thead/row/entry/node()" />
</xsl:template>
```

I am getting this output:

```
<table frame="all" class="- topic/table ">
                <tgroup id="topic_61_tg_2" cols="1" class="- topic/tgroup ">
                    <colspec colname="col1" colwidth="480pt" class="- topic/colspec "/>
                    <thead class="- topic/thead ">
                        <row class="- topic/row ">
                            <entry valign="middle" class="- topic/entry ">
                                <i>italic text title</i>
                            </entry>
                        </row>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="- topic/tbody ">
                        <row class="- topic/row ">
                            <entry class="- topic/entry "/>
                        </row>
                    </tbody>
                </tgroup>
            </table>
```

As you can see, the table and not the image was preserved. Any idea of what I am doing wrong here? I'd also like to note that there is a lot of other content in this XML file that I want to preserve as well, that is why I tried `<xsl:template match="table//image">` for that `copy-of` part

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what "no other content" means? In your example, the table also contains an `<i>` tag with text in, which could be classed as "other content". Thanks!

Comment: When I say no other content, I mean that there are embedded images that are interpreted as tables in my Word XML. I want to preserve the image and the image title (the <i> tag), but get rid of all the rest of the table tags for these embedded images. My first code snippet shows an example of one of these image tables, you can see that there is no other content in the table other than the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:for-each select="descendant::image">
        <xsl:element name="fig">
            <xsl:element name="title">
                <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::i"/>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Like some of the other answers, this is really close to what I want. Perhaps I should have worded this part better " I'd also like to note that there is a lot of other content in this XML file that I want to preserve as well". I should have indicated that some of this other content are tables without images. As in, I want to keep those types of tables, right now, those are getting purged with this code. I'll try and modify this code and some of the other answers that were given.

Comment: I ended up changing the second line to `<xsl:template match="table[.//image]">`. This helped to preserve my normal tables. Could you update this in your code so I can mark this answer as correct?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="table">
        <xsl:for-each select="//image">
            <xsl:element name="fig">
                <xsl:element name="title">
                    <xsl:value-of select="following-sibling::i"/>
                </xsl:element>
                <xsl:element name="image">
                    <xsl:attribute name="href">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@href"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="width">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@width"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="height">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@height"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="image">

    </xsl:template>
    Try it
```

Comment: This is close to what I want. I'm going to try and tweak this. Right now, my input file has 2 such tables, but I am getting 3 sets of XML per image (6 in all) and my two normal tables that I want to preserve are getting deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
<xsl:template match="table"><!-- Match table instead of matching image -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="tgroup/thead/row/entry//image" /><!-- than copy image through its XPath -->
</xsl:template>
```

In your example you match template for `image` and mentioned `xpath` for `table`. therefore it is not worked.